# How i pass parameters together with registerReceiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I create an application for send incoming call number to bluetooth work fine.Now i want pass admin number user from activity to receiver.How i can do this?I try something but my apk crash...
after adding the pass variable method...I want send bt signal if admin call...

```
   public void onResume() {
 super.onResume();

 registerReceiver(new IncomingCallReceiver(), new   intentFilter("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"));

//Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
//intent.putExtra("admin_no",strAdmin); // change number here.
//sendBroadcast(intent);

wl.acquire();

}

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

           // String admin2 = intent.getStringExtra("admin_no");

            if(null == bundle)
                    return;

            Log.i("IncomingCallReceiver",bundle.toString());

            String state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

            Log.i("IncomingCallReceiver","State: "+ state);

            if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
            {
                    String phonenumber =  bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            Log.i("IncomingCallReceiver","Incomng Number: " + phonenumber);

                    String info = "Detect call... \nIncoming number: " + phonenumber;

                    Toast.makeText(context, info, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                   if(info.indexOf(admin)>0){


                     //Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm service!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                          //Intent service = new Intent(context, Btservice.class);

                         //context.startService(service);

                         //String msg = intent.getStringExtra("data");

                   try {
                         //DetectCallBt.sendDataBT(bat);
                        Activity2.sendDataBT("1");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                         //TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
   }
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: but PHONE_STATE action Broadcast by system so i think it's not possible to send any data to it at this time of registration and receive same in onReceive method . u will need to explain more to get right solution of problem instead of asking same question again-2

Comment: I want send bluetooth signal only if admin user number call...

Comment: @AntonisKan : can u plz explain it more

Comment: I try different way from activity pass variable to function...as static.Thanks!